# LinkedIn Connections Access

Tags: linkedin-api

Problem Description:
I am working on a product that leverages linkedIn user data. I want to be able to extract users connections ( when you add someone and they accept - you become a connection ). This data is private but should be able to be shared through the LinkedIn API. I have browsed it for a long time, but could not find a definite answer to my question.

I have tried a few approaches. Firstly, I checked the LinkedIn API documentation, which states that the API exists. They had some notes on the recent changes and limitations made - stated that it is available through request.

[Documentation Notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZEvq.png)

Contacted the form they provided, no definitive answer was given. I have browsed the resources on Stack Overflow yet there were no recent tickets created.  I also checked the authentication link on the documentation and the portal, found that you could get the access token through there to extract the data. I researched the process - which is self explanatory - but couldn't find a way to extract the connections data after.

Finally, I gave up till i saw an app requesting my connections.

Comment: I'm wondering where you looked.  I googled "become linkedin developer" and the VERY FIRST HIT is "Apply | LinkedIn Developer Network".

Comment: Let me rephrase, I have already seen the application location. I have also checked the developer portal. I couldn't identify any way to extract the connections data after. My question is more directed towards how to access the connection data after the login rather than the login access itself

Comment: Have you read the limitations?  You can only see that data if the user has permitted it.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/connections-api